# how to make a recursive racket list that, from the input list, outputs its decreasing to 1 for every element in the list (e.g. ('3 2) outputs ('32121)

Tags: list, recursion, racket

****What I tried****

```
(define(help num)
        (if(= num 1)
           num
          (cons(num (help( - num 1))))))
```

;i called this defination in the bottom one

```
(define (list-expand L)
(cond
  [(empty? L)'()]
  [(=(car L)1)(cons(car L)(list-expand (cdr L)))]
  [(>(car L)1) (cons(help(car L)(list-expand(cdr L))))]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `help` procedure, the base case is incorrect - if the output is a list then you must return a list. And in the recursive step, `num` is not a procedure, so it must not be surrounded by brackets:

```
(define (help num)
  (if (<= num 0)
      '()
      (cons num (help (- num 1)))))
```

And in `list-expand`, both recursive steps are incorrect. You just need to test whether the list is empty or not, calling `help` with the correct number of parameters; use `append` to combine the results, because we're concatenating sublists together:

```
(define (list-expand L)
  (if (empty? L)
      '()
      (append (help (car L)) (list-expand (cdr L)))))
```

That should work as expected, but please spend some time studying Scheme's syntax, you still have trouble with the basics, for instance, when and where to use brackets...

```
(list-expand '(3 2))
=> '(3 2 1 2 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun - a non-recursive solution in Racket:

```
(append-map (lambda (n) (stream->list (in-range n 0 -1))) '(3 2))

;; or:
(append-map (lambda (n) (for/list ((x (in-range n 0 -1))) x)) '(3 2))
```

Returning:

```
'(3 2 1 2 1)
```